# Cómo superponer dos imágenes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Necesito poner una imagen con transparencia encima de otra, y no veo cómo hacerlo porque estoy usando Bootstrap, el código es éste:

```
{% for promocion in promociones %}
    <div class="col-sm-4 polygraphy element isotope-item">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="item_wrapper">
                <div class="img_block">
                    {% if promocion.foto %}
                        <img style="z-index: 1" src="/promocionesImg/{{ promocion.foto }}" class="img-responsive imgPrevia2">
                        {% if '1' == promocion.activa %}
                            <img style="z-index: 300" src="{{ asset('images/active.png') }}">;
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                    <a class="featured_ico_link view_link" href="{{ path("promociones_ficha", { 'idPromocion': promocion.id }) }}"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="featured_items_body">
                    <div class="featured_items_title">{{ promocion.nombre }}</div>
                    <div class="featured_meta">{{ promocion.descripcion }}<br>{{ promocion.fechaini|date('d/m/Y') }}</div>
                    <a class="sigue-leyendo" href="{{ path("promociones_ficha", { 'idPromocion': promocion.id }) }}">{{ "Sigue.leyendo"|trans }}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Necesito poner la imagen `active.png` encima de la otra imagen y no sé cómo hacerlo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si quieres poner una imagen encima de la otra, ambas imágenes deben estar posicionadas de forma **absoluta**, en otro caso no se pueden colocar una encima de la otra.

Una vez tienes una foto sobre la otra debes hacer uso del [Z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) para indicar en qué orden se deben renderizar las imágenes.

Te dejo este [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h1gwyLeb/13/) para que veas cómo funciona: La imagen del ojo es un .PNG con transparencias y su z-index es superior al de la otra, una imagen .JPG que actúa de fondo.

```css
.eye{
  position:absolute;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  top: 40px;
  left : 40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.heaven
{
  position:absolute;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
  <img src="https://pre00.deviantart.net/a22b/th/pre/i/2015/109/c/e/blue_eye_3b_saved_as_png_to_preserve_transparency_by_shadowprince14-d8qbizi.png" class='eye'/>
  <img src="https://d2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net/video/thumbnail/Vv03xyNwg/white-heaven-background_ryb1grtbx_thumbnail-full11.png" class="heaven"/>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te he añadido el fiddle aqui, para no depender de páginas externas :)

Comment: Perfecto, gracias Pablo, estoy acostumbrado a StackOverflow inglés y tienen esa mala costumbre que me la han pegado :P